# Retrieving words from database with codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have recently started using codeigniter and I am a bit stuck as it is all rather new to me.

I use to have a config file with database conection and this on it:

```
$qset = "select * from re_settings";
$rset = mysql_query($qset) or die(mysql_error());
$aset = mysql_fetch_array($rset);
```

and this would allow me to pull words from database by simply putting this on the site

```
<?=$aset['SiteTitle']?>
```

How can I do this in codeigniter? Do I need to have a controller to do this or is it something much simpler than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to become familiar with the concepts of MCV which is how Codeigniter is built on and your ORM framework.

There's a bunch of helpful resources on http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/ or the official docs http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html

as an example

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, title, email FROM my_table');

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['email'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Filype. I just found this in the manual and was about to answer my own question. I appreciate your time to help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use Datamapper along with CodeIgniter.
You will be surprised on how it is easy to work with your MySQL database.

Say goodbye to "mysql_fetch_array" 's and such.

Have a look : http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html

Comment: Hi, i did have installed codeignitor but there has been no updates for over a year and looks rather dead. Tried to install Datamapper but could not get it to work as it was asking me to put files in folders that were no longer there so was not sure where to put them. I have reverted back to php and getting on a lot better.

Comment: Mmm... You're truly missing something in terms of productivity when you don't use a framework nowadays, but that's your call. I personally prefered to insist and try it, and it paid off. Laravel is more active, but Codeigniter/Datamapper is perfect for programming REST APIs in a blaze. And it still will be in five years. Just think of the time it took to go from PHP4 to PHP5. Codeigniter is a rare case of a mature framework that is so lightweight and yet powerful, that it doesn't age: If you need more functionalities, you have at disposal all the PHP librairies in the world to attach to.

Comment: Notice I did not say it WON'T age. We all do eventually :-)

Comment: ok @Bonatoc i will give it another go. My navbar in php is database written and creates pages from the backend panel but this seems to be complicated in codeigniter. Do you have any gide on this for me?